# Disable the confirmation of shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I have upgraded to 13.04 and now when I click on to the setting -. shut-down the is this stupid bar across asking if i want to shut-down, restart etc.
This was disables in all my previous versions, via gconf-editor and Tweak.

I have tried the terminal commands that are posted on the web and all the other information posted.

Can someone tell me how to remove this stupid Microsoft feature, when i cl lick ok to the shut-down button, I want to shut-down otherwise I would have pressed the restart or suspend button.

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score -1):

Make an executable bash script on your desktop:

```
touch ~/Desktop/shutdown.sh; chmod +x shutdown.sh
```

Then, open the file, and paste the following inside:

```
#!/bin/bash

gksu shutdown now
```

And, then, whenever you want to shutdown, just execute the file. :)

UPDATE: Try this instead:

Change [password] to your password, and then save this into a file `shutdown.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shutdown
Exec=echo [password] | sudo -S shutdown now
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/
```

Now, double-click to shutdown. You can also make one `reboot.desktop`, just change the part where it says shutdown to reboot. Hope this helps!

Comment: Problem x 2. Two pop-up screens. First one to ask what to do with the shutdown.sh file. If your answer is 'Run' or 'Run in terminal' then you will be asked for your administrator password.

Comment: True... I'll get back to you in a few hours, I'm reading the .desktop spec.

Comment: Try this instead!